# Nginx proxy to CFSS Connection refused

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, cfssl

I have [CFSSL](https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl) service running in kubernetes on port `8888`. I can access it API's from another pod directly referring `cfssl:8888`. I want to expose it via Nginx and I have Nginx running in separate pod with following config

```
upstream cfssl {
    server cfssl:8888;
}

server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    listen         [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name    localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://cfssl;
        proxy_set_header Host cfssl;
    }
}
```

But this Nginx config is not working, I can access `cfssl:8888` wethin Nginx pod, but when I do `curl localhost:80`

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

What is wrong in this setup ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside location block you have not mention port

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://cfssl;
```

it should be something like

```
server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    listen         [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name    localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://cfssl:8888;
        proxy_set_header Host cfssl;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, still same error when I do curl localhost:80, curl localhost or curl nginx:80, `curl nginx` within nginx container

Comment: if you using containers can't you write ingress?